# Sum checkboxes and select options together

Tags: jquery, checkbox, sum

I am hoping to add the values of multiple select options and also checkboxes together using jQuery but have got a little stuck.  My primary issue is that I receive NaN as my combined answer.

I initially just summed dropdowns which worked (an example can be found at http://pure.evolvedublin.com/phone) but now need to add checkboxes into the mix (as seen at http://pure.evolvedublin.com/broadband-phone).

When you click the Start button on both pages, the values become available.

I have tried using the solutions found in [jQuery checkbox and select - sum the values and add in var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066649/jquery-checkbox-and-select-sum-the-values-and-add-in-var) and [jQuery update initial price on click on checkbox that has data-price attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431430/jquery-update-initial-price-on-click-on-checkbox-that-has-data-price-attribute) but have not been able to get them working.

My jsfiddle with a sample of my code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/damienoneill2001/77Hhd/

I am using the following code to add the checkboxes, but just dont have it right:

```
jQuery('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    tot=0;
    jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    tot+=parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
});
tot+=parseFloat(document.getElementById("broadband_package").value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById("irish_mobile_package").value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById("intl_landline_package").value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById("intl_mob_package").value);
    jQuery('.cost-container').text(tot);
    jQuery('.cost-containerb').val(tot);
});

jQuery('.broad .irish_mob').change(function(){
    jQuery('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
});
```

The values should also only add to the total when the Add button is pressed.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The following values return `undefined` when I first check something:

```
document.getElementById("intl_landline_package").value
document.getElementById("intl_mob_package").value
```

This is because these are `div`s, not `selects`, so `value` is undefined. You will need to loop through the checkboxes in these divs and add up their values individually.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this idea has got me on the right track.  I know have a problem with the checkboxes adding up incorrectly which I am running through!  Thanks for your help with this one